# Clone html element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement drag and drop system in angularjs.

I want dragged object to be cloned on drag start. However I have no idea how to clone an element along with it's scope and linked controller in angularjs?

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's [angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) for deep copying, but I'm not sure what you mean by "...along with it's scope and linked controller...".

Comment: The "destination" parameter in angular.clone ethod is defined as: {(Object|Array)=} but i'm trying to clone html element with, listeners, scope, controller and everything. I want to create the clone of dragged html element (a directive).

Comment: I see. Maybe you'll want to edit your question and replace 'object' with 'element'.

Comment: ohhh, right. thx for noticing it.

Answer (score 10):

Cloning DOM elements as it is usually done for drag & drop is not recommended with Angular. Instead, clone your object model.

Let's say you display items in an `<UL>` and have another dragged item visible only while dragging:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="{{item.shadow}}">{{item.text}}</li>
<ul>
<div ng-show="draggedItem != null">{{draggedItem.text}}</div>
```

and in the controller, make a copy of the item to drag into draggedItem:

```
$scope.items = [{text:"First"}, {text:"Second"}];
$scope.shadowItem = null; // Item at the original position
$scope.draggedItem = null; // Clone item being moved

$scope.dragStart = function(item) {
    $scope.shadowItem = item;
    $scope.draggedItem = angular.copy(item);
    item.shadow = "shadow"; // set a CSS class to change its look
    // From now on, the DIV is dragged around
}

$scope.drop = function() {
    // Save the new item position
    $scope.draggedItem = null; // Makes the dragged clone item disappear
    $scope.shadowItem.shadow = ""; // give the item its normal look back
}
```

Comment: What am I doing is creating the "Actions". And every "Action" is different. So I've got for example UndoAction or ShowAllAction and so on. All of thous has carries different funtionality and has different graphical representation (these are different directives). What i want to do is similar to draggable skills in World of Warcraft. I know it's not recommended but I don't see any other solution.

Comment: All items you are moving are Actions. It doesn't matter that they have different graphical representations. You can put inside the `<li>` all the representations, each with its conditional attribute: `ng-show="item.kind=='UndoAction'"` for the first, `ng-show="item.kind=='ShowAllAction'"` for the next, etc. Then you can apply my method above.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue wrapping a library which cloned my nodes. This is my solution:

```
angular.module('my-module')
.directive('mqAllowExternalClone', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: link,
  };

  function link(scope, elem, attr) {
    var element = elem[0];
    var original = element.cloneNode;
    element.cloneNode = patch;

    function patch(deep) {
      var clone = original.call(element, deep);

      // You can remove this two lines and the result
      //   will be more or less the same.
      // In my case I need it for other reasons
      clone.removeAttribute('mq-allow-external-clone');
      clone.cloneNode = patch;

      $compile(clone)(scope);
      return clone;
    }
  }
});
```

https://gist.github.com/amatiasq/ae6fce9acf74589ef36d

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it but the idea was exactly that, if I improve or fix any bug on it the link will have the last version.