# ng-model doesn't work when dragging and dropping an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-ngmodel

ng-model doesn't work when I drag and **copy** an input box, here is my code :

```html
 <input type="text" ng-model="test"  draggable item="items" id="1">
{{test}}

 <!--destination -->
 <md-content class="bin" drop="handleDrop" droppable  >
        </md-content>
{{test}}
```

If I use the input box in the source item, the ng-model works, but when I bring it to  the destination it doesn't work.Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/NbggxK?editors=1010) 
thank you for help 
**Update**
I figure out that when I drag&**drop** the input the I can get the value of `test` in the source, and **not** in the destination (but it's ok for me ) 
here is an [example](http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/qqjjOp?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and based on that [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436877/clone-html-element-in-angularjs) I find a solution.
the problem was that the cloned code doesn't compile,so angular doesn't know that the ng-model(for example) existe, but after compiling the code using $compile, it works

Comment: here is an example:  http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/zodQLx?editors=1010 (cannot add a link)